# missing 1 required positional argument: 'offset'

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, offset

This piece of code could not be executed:

```
def hours_ahead(request, offset):
    try:
        offset = int(offset)
    except ValueError:
        raise Http404()
    dt = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(hours=offset)
    html = "<html><body>In %s hour(s), it will be %s.</body></html>" % (offset, dt)
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

It returns this error message:

```
hours_ahead() missing 1 required positional argument: 'offset'
```

I have Python 3.3 installed. Is there anything I'm missing here?

Comment: And how is this method called? The `offset` parameters is not being passed.

Comment: How are you calling the function?  Post the full traceback.

Comment: Is this a Django view? What is the URL route config?

Comment: Thanks for your replys, You mentioned url configs and I can see that there is something wrong in my regular expression:     `url(r'^time/plus/\d+/$', hours_ahead),`

Comment: give a try on this :url(r'^time/plus/(\d+)/$', hours_ahead)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I Changed:

```
url(r'^time/plus/\d+/$', hours_ahead)
```

to:

```
url(r'^time/plus/(\d+)/$', hours_ahead)
```

and apparently it fixed my problem.